# Merge two data frames and retrieve all the information from the right data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Hi Stack Overflow community. I am new to spark/pyspark and I have this question.

Say I have two data frames (`df2` being the interest data set with a lot of records and `df1` is a new update). I want to join the two data frames on multiple columns (if possible) and get the updated information from `df1` when there is a key match otherwise keep the `df2` information as it is.

here is my sample data set and my expected output (`df30`)

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 4, 'x'), ("b",  3, 'y'), ("c", 4, 'z'), ("d", 4, 'l')], ["C1", "C2", "C3"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 4, 5), ("f", 3, 4), ("b", 3, 6), ("c", 4, 7), ("d", 4, 8)], ["C1", "C2","C3"])
df1_s = df1.select([col(c).alias('s_' + c) for c in df1.columns])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use left join on your list of columns and using a list comprehension over the remaining columns select updates using the `coalesce` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

join_columns = ["C1"]

result = df2.alias("df2").join(
    df1.alias("df1"),
    join_columns,
    "left"
).select(
    *join_columns,
    *[
        F.coalesce(f"df1.{c}", f"df2.{c}").alias(c)
        for c in df1.columns if c not in join_columns
    ]
)

result.show()
#+---+---+---+
#| C1| C2| C3|
#+---+---+---+
#|  f|  3|  4|
#|  d|  4|  l|
#|  c|  4|  z|
#|  b|  3|  y|
#|  a|  4|  x|
#+---+---+---+
```